# Rest api response data not saved in the database using Spring JPA

Tags: java, database, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm new with anything Spring related, so would you please help me with this? I'm trying to write a registration api that saves some data in the database using Spring JPA.

Here is my code:

@Entity model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registerapplications")
public class RegisterApplication {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; 

    private String applicationId;

    public RegisterApplication (String applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    // Getters and Setter
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface RegisterRepository extends CrudRepository<RegisterApplication, Long>{

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class RegisterApplicationController {

    @Autowired
    private RegisterRepository registerRepository;

    @RequestMapping (path="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody RegisterApplication registerApplicationController() {
        RegisterApplication registerApplication = new RegisterApplication(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        registerRepository.save(registerApplication);
        return registerApplication;
    }   
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/register
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

The request works properly, but it does not save the data in my table: [Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cySNH.png)

I get no error, so I don't know where the problem is. Would you please take a look on the code and give me some hints?

Comment: what's the response? what did you send to `/register`?

Comment: I have no request body. This is the response: {
    "id": 1,
    "applicationId": "fc1d499e-133c-42de-912d-082957d0baca"
} and I want to add the id and the applicationId in the database in the registerapplications table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for your problem is that you forgot to annotate the `applicationId` field in your `entity` with `@Column`.

Comment: @deedee88 did you create your db-table manually? Because it has more columns than defined in the entity. Maybe delete that table and let JPA create it

Comment: I tried with only those 2 columns and I also tried to let JPA create the table, but it doesn't create it

Comment: Are there any sql logs ? Add `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to your `application.proprties` to enable sql logging

Comment: After many changes, I managed to fix the issue. I think the main problem was that the resources package was under the java package, instead of the main package. And from there I went from error to error until it worked. Thank you for your help Valentin.